# Use GPU to speed up server processing

Tags: multi-threading, graphics-processing-unit

I have a server that handles strings of data pushed from another server. Sometimes we receive thousands a second. This might be overly simplistic but would putting a Graphics card in the server assist in processing these strings quicker?  Sometimes there can be 15s delay. which is not acceptable for the application we are using the server for.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes. GPUs are optimised for parallel processing, and I believe that can be the solution of your problem. I have dealt with Nvidia Tesla GPUs on an IIS Server before, and they work extremely well even under heavy load. May I ask which operating system/ solution you are implementing on your server?

Comment: You failed to mention that the application will need to be re-written to take advantage of the GPU. As written, you make it sound like throwing a GPU in will magically make things perform better.

Comment: And perhaps the GPU may not be faster than the existing CPU in this particular situation. Further research/benchmarking would be required.